# How to run Lightning Test Service (LTS) from Jenkins hosted on AWS against e.g. BrowserStack?

Tags: aws, lightning-testing-service

We run Karma and Protractor Angular tests from a Jenkins continuous integration (CI) server hosted on AWS. Those two frameworks allow the browser to be run remotely in e.g. https://www.browserstack.com so we can run the tests across a large number of browsers and browser versions. (And a recording of the screen is kept too which makes the debugging of failed UI tests much, much easier.)

Ideally we would like to run Lightning Test Service (LTS) in the same way. The only snippet of relevant information we've found is https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/issues/46 which AFAIK is aiming to run "Headless Chrome" locally. And that requires what looks like some poorly documented setup.

Any suggestions on how to setup a configuration to a remote instance of Selenium such as BrowserStack's offering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about something like,

```
sfdx force:lightning:test:run -f config/lts-config.json
```

where 'lts-config.json' contains a config like,

```
{
    "webdriverio": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "chrome"
      },
      "host": "hub.browserstack.com",
      "port": 80,
      "user" : "your_username",
      "key" : "your_key"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Emad, thanks for answering. Can you also provide links to documentation or explain why you think this will work? Presume you haven't tried it?

Comment: I looked at the sample provided by webdriverio at https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/cloudservices/webdriverio.browserstack.js and converted it into the format described at https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/issues/46#issuecomment-347928851 . I do agree that LTS repo needs more documentation around the configuration by the way. Hopefully we can fix that soon. I did give it a quick try by the way (works for me).

Comment: Thanks for those clarifications. Will get back to this soon encouraged by your testing working.