# Authenticate to send a GET request to a lighting page

Tags: api, authentication, accesstoken

i would like to ask if it is possible to get a token that allows you to receive the html of a lightning or visualforce page given the url. The REST api token doesnt seem to work. For example get the /home page as html in curl. Thank you

Comment: This sounds like a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? Please edit your question.

Comment: I want to send a post request to a setup page, to automate the enablement of a setting which not available in metadata api. So i first want to get access to the setup page via curl for testing.

Comment: Selenium is the popular choice for this task, e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210954/what-do-you-use-to-automate-the-testing-of-your-lightning-components

Comment: If you're just making HTTP requests, you need to hit the frontdoor URL with a valid token and preserve all the cookies you get. Then you'll be able to hit at least some setup pages (that don't require a CSRF token). But as identigral said, some flavor of browser automation (Selenium, Robot Framework) is likely to be needed.